# Need optimized select query

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

Consider below schema:

```
Tables: Tasks (tid, jobid, status, name)
        Jobs(jobid, submitTime)
```

Here I can have multiple tasks table rows with one jobid. Now I want to fetch all rows from Tasks table such that their status=5 and all other rows with the same jobid should also be 5.

eg: I have 5 rows in Tasks, first 2 with jobid=1 and status=5, last 3 with jobid=2 and two with status=5 and 1 with status=4. My query should only return first two rows with jobid=1 as all rows with jobid=1 have status=5. Rows with jobid=2 should not be returned, as one row with jobid=2 have status=4.

I need help in constructing an optimized query assuming I have some 300K rows in Tasks table.

```
mysql> select * from task;
+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
| taskid | jobid | status | name                 |
+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
|      1 |     1 |      5 | Task 1, Job 1        |
|      2 |     1 |      5 | Task 2, Job 1        |
|      3 |     2 |      5 | Task 3, Job 2        |
|      4 |     2 |      5 | Task 4, Job 2        |
|      5 |     2 |      4 | Task 5, Job 2 status |
+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from job;
+-------+---------------------+
| jobid | time                |
+-------+---------------------+
|     1 | 2016-07-15 15:13:42 |
|     2 | 2016-07-15 15:13:44 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Output I need:

```
+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
| taskid | jobid | status | name                 |
+--------+-------+--------+----------------------+
|      1 |     1 |      5 | Task 1, Job 1        |
|      2 |     1 |      5 | Task 2, Job 1        |
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show input and desired output as tables.  I cannot translate your description into tabular form.

Comment: How `jobs` table is related with your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added

Comment: @mitkosoft You can say it's not related and assume jobid as independent value. But My query needs that if two rows has same jobid but one has status!=5, none of the two rows should be returned from output.

Comment: It seems like a simple `WHERE` clause should work.  If not, then your sample does not reveal more complexity in the query.  Throw some indices in there and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks t
WHERE t.`status` = 5
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tasks tt
    WHERE t.jobid = tt.jobid
    AND tt.`status` <> 5
)
```

Output:

```
+-----+-------+--------+---------------+
| tid | jobid | status | name          |
+-----+-------+--------+---------------+
|   1 |     1 |      5 | Task 1, Job 1 |
|   2 |     1 |      5 | Task 2, Job 1 |
+-----+-------+--------+---------------+
2 rows in set
```

On top of that consider adding indexes on `status` and `jobid` columns:

```
ALTER TABLE `tasks` 
    ADD INDEX `status_IDX` (`status`),
    ADD INDEX `jobid_IDX` (`jobid`);
```

Or better just one composite index over both fields:

```
ALTER TABLE `tasks` 
    ADD INDEX `composite_IDX` (`status`,`jobid`);
```

Which index you will choose depends on that what kind of queries you will perform against that table. In this particular case the composite one is better choice.

Comment: No, this would be best:  `INDEX(jobid, status)` and `INDEX(status)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `LEFT JOIN` to the same table, that will join to all records with `status <> 5`.
Then you can exclude any record that got results from this `JOIN`.

And indeed, adding indexes on `status` and `jobid` will improve performance.

```
SELECT t.taskid, t.jobid, t.status, t.name
FROM task t
LEFT JOIN task t2
    ON t.jobid = t2.jobid 
    AND t.taskid  <> t.taskid 
    AND t.status <> 5
WHERE t.status = 5
AND t2.taskid IS NULL
GROUP BY t.taskid
```

Let me know if this works!
Good luck :)

Comment: That needs `INDEX(jobid)` and `INDEX(status, taskid)`.